# How to do the problem with group by when solving a problem?

Tags: sql

I was doing problems at SQLZoo and got stuck at question 7, they have provided solution using nested query but how do I do this with group by?
Link to the problem: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

I tried this

```
select continent, name, area
from world
where area = (select max(area) from world
              group by continent);
```

But the response come as 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: Either do IN, or skip GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `=` operator you need a co-related subquery to make sure that only a single row is returned:

```
select w1.continent, w1.name, w1.area
from world w1
where w1.area = (select max(w2.area) 
                 from world w2
                 where w2.continent = w1.continent);
```

Another option is to use the IN operator with two columns then you can keep the `group by` in the sub-select.

```
select continent, name, area
from world
where (continent, area) IN (select continent, max(area) 
                            from world
                            group by continent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select continent, name, area
from world
where area IN (select max(area) from world
              group by continent);
```

Comment: Note that this relies on the fact that the area is unique. If that isn't the case, this might return the wrong result (e.g. if the largest country on one continent was as big as the second-largest in another)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to number rows grouped by continent descending by area.

```
select continent, name, area
from (
    select 
    continent, 
    name, 
    area,
    row_number() over (partition by continent order by area desc) as rn
    from world ) world
    where world.rn = 1
```